# Сan I configure FreeBSD to use DHCP or a static IP depending on the detected ssid?

Tags: freebsd, wifi

I have a FreeBSD 8 machine which can use several wireless access points. I want it to use the first available network and automatically use DHCP or a static address as required. Is it possible under FreeBSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into NetworkManager (http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/)?

Comment: I'm not sure if NetworkManager already ported to FreeBSD.

Comment: It looks like there has been "talk" dating back to 2009 by some.

Answer (score 1):

Check http://opal.com/freebsd/ports/net-mgmt/wifimgr/